# Не получается перенести modx с локалки на хостинг

Tags: modx, хостинг, localhost

База данных, подключается успешно, отображается только главная страница, остальные - показывает главную без стилей. При входе в админку пустая страница. Уже несколько раз переустанавливал. В предыдущих установках показывало инпуты с админки без стилей, в том случае я обнаружил, что путь был указан неправильный, лишний /modx/ был. И логин пароль в том случае не подходили, которые были на локалке.
Версия Revo-2.6.3-pl. Посмотреть можно [тут](http://bolgary.aleksandernitchenko.ru/)

Comment: нужно указать версию modx

Comment: добавил в описание